# How to divide 2 views without a straight line?

Tags: react-native, view, frontend

Imagine I want to create a view like the picture below. Is there any workaround? Anything beyond creating and using a photo as the background image.
http://i68.tinypic.com/2w6z4o1.jpg

Comment: Are you just looking to create a two color screen like that or does each color block need to function as a separate view?  I think react-native-linear-gradient can apply two colors to a view like that but they wouldn't function as separate views https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

Comment: No, Actually I want them both to be functional. @GarrettMcCullough

Comment: How would you do it in native environment (iOS or Android)?

Comment: I only take advantage of react in frontend development. idk @vovkasm

Comment: I asked, because method make such views in RN the same as in native applications. But, afaik, it is very hard task in general case. It can be simplified, in some specific cases, for ex: 3 rectangle views: top for top view, middle - decoration with diagonal, bottom for bottom view.

Comment: When you say that you want them to be functional, what do you mean?  Are you expecting the text, sub-views, etc to also flow at an angle?

Comment: actually, I want to be able to use them. eg. be able to put a Text component in them and show a text in them. @GarrettMcCullough

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate effects to achieve here:

1. Background gradient - just use this assuming a linear gradient is acceptable: [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient)
2. Non-horizontal line. You can achieve this by using a rotation transformation on a `View`, and doing a reverse transformation on an inner view. You will need to order it correctly to make it sit above its sibling (last element is higher than the previous). E.g.

`<View style={{transform: [{rotate: rotation}]}}>
  <View style={{transform: [{rotate: -rotation}]}}>
    {children}
  </View>
</View>`